# What is the last meal during the period of sukkot, and the days following, for which sefaradim are required to sit in the sukkah?

Tags: halacha, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, chutz-laaretz, sukkot, shmini-atzeres

What is the last meal during the period of sukkot, and the days following, for which sefaradim are required to sit in the sukkah? There are different minhagim with this issue. Which minhag do sefaradim follow in diaspora? What does Hacham Ovadia Yosef say?

Comment: What minhagim have you observed and who was observing them?

Comment: @DoubleAA, my recollection is failing me, but I think that Chabad and Chasidim sit in the sukkah even on Simchat Torah evening (or at least all of Shmini Atzeret).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 668:1 rules that in chutz l'aretz one is required to eat in the sukkah, but that one does not make the beracha of lasheiv basukkah. The Kaf HaHayyim 668:8 rules that this applies to all eating (not just the seudot), but that someone who is machmir to not eat fruit outside the sukkah on Sukkot can be meikil on Shemini Atzeret.

The Ben Ish Chai (Parshat Vezot HaBeracha 13) also rules that one is required to eat in the sukkah, without the beracha.

Yalkut Yosef omitted the din of Shemini Atzeret in Chutz l'Aretz completely, but in Chazon Ovadia Sukkot, R' Ovadia Yosef rules that one is required to eat in the sukkah, without the beracha.

Comment: The sources are much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

http://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/1646477/jewish/How-is-Sukkot-Observed.htm:

> **36: Is there an obligation to sit in the Sukkah on Shemini Atzeret in the diaspora?**
>
> According to most opinions, the Yom Tov meals must be
> eaten in the Sukkah. The blessing for the Sukkah is certainly not
> recited. One may have snacks and drinks in the house, since even on
> Sukkot there is no obligation to have them in the Sukkah. Some have
> the custom to be lenient on Shemini Atzeret and eat some or all of the
> Yom Tov meal in the house. A person should not be lenient unless he
> has a strong family custom regarding this.

Comment: How does this answer your question which asks about sefardim??

Comment: "Most opinions" like, say, the Talmud Bavli.

Comment: @DoubleAA, nobody offered an answer--this was the best I could do.

Comment: Patience, my friend.

Comment: @DoubleAA, this seems to be the custom for the sephardim in my local morocon shul.